# Extract audio from rtsp link for Android

Tags: android, rtsp

I am creating a playlist app for Android. I have an rtsp link to the third party server where the media is stored. I am able to play the rtsp using VideoView provided by Android. I don't want to stream the video as I am interested in audio only. So I can save bandwith and it will be faster. But I am not sure how to extract audio only from an rtsp link for Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can play audio streams only if your server is streaming audio and video in non aggregation mode. In non aggragation mode you can use `PLAY` command seprately for audio and video.

your sdp may look like this

```
           v=0
           o=- 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 192.16.24.202
           s=RTSP Session
           m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
           a=control:rtsp://audio.example.com/twister/audio.en
           m=video 0 RTP/AVP 31
           a=control:rtsp://video.example.com/twister/video
```

send SETUP for AUDIO

```
C->A: SETUP rtsp://audio.example.com/twister/audio.en RTSP/1.0
           CSeq: 1
           Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=3056-3057

     A->C: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
           CSeq: 1
           Session: 12345678
           Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=3056-3057;
                      server_port=5000-5001
```

send PLAY for AUDIO

```
C->A: PLAY rtsp://audio.example.com/twister/audio.en RTSP/1.0
           CSeq: 2
           Session: 12345678
           Range: smpte=0:10:00-

     A->C: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
           CSeq: 2
           Session: 12345678
           Range: smpte=0:10:00-0:20:00
           RTP-Info: url=rtsp://audio.example.com/twister/audio.en;
             seq=876655;rtptime=1032181
```

Please refer section 14.1 of RFC 2326

If uou receive error 460 in response to `PLAY` , it means server doesnot support non aggregation mdoe. In this case it is not possible to stream AUDIO and VIDEO seprately

```
M->C: RTSP/1.0 460 Only aggregate operation allowed
           CSeq: 5
```